# Split amount among quantites

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm to split an amount into single item add-on value.
The easiest way to explain this is to show an example.
Let's imagine an amount of 8.13 and following items

```
Item   Qty    Price   Item totals
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1       2     1.00       2.00
 2       3     2.00       6.00
 3      11     3.00      33.00
                  Total: 41.00
         Expected total: 41.00 + 8.13 = 49.13
```

The closest amounts I found for each item to get in total the extra 8.13 were:

```
Item   Qty    Price    Add-on amount  Final Price   Item totals
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1       2     1.00       0.52           1.52          3.04
 2       3     2.00       0.53           2.53          7.59
 3      11     3.00       0.50           3.50         38.50
                                               Total: 49.13
```

Is there any algorithm that solves this problem? Number of items can vary, sometimes quantities can repeat, etc.

**Update 1**

As stated in one of the comments, I would like to avoid rounding. In such situation I realize that there will be scenarios that will leave me with some amounts that is impossible to split evenly without rounding i.e.

```
Item   Qty    Price  Item totals      Add-on amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1       5       1.00         5.00         0.01
 2       5       2.00        10.00         0.01
 3       5       3.00        15.00         0.01
                      Total: 30.00   Rest: 0.02
             Expected total: 30.00 + 0.17 = 30.17
```

In my original example, when I calculated the add-on amounts, I didn't take the price into consideration, as my primary goal is to split the amount evenly, not necessarily proportionally. However if there is a solution that solves this problem with splitting amount proportionally, I will be more than happy to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define the parameters you have:

> *Q<sub>i</sub>* = quantity of item *i*
> *P<sub>i</sub>* = price of item *i*
> *T* = total = *Σ<sub>i=1..n</sub> (Q<sub>i</sub> × P<sub>i</sub>)*
> *TA* = total add-on amount
> *TQ* = total quantity = *Σ<sub>i=1..n</sub> (Q<sub>i</sub>)*
> *A<sub>i</sub>* = add-on amount for item *i* (to be determined)

Then you could do this in two steps. First determine a lower bound for each of the A<sub>i</sub> and what remains of the add-on after that:

> *AL* = lower bound for *A<sub>i</sub>* (for all *i*, as we aim for even distribution across items)
> *R* = remainder of TA that needs to be distributed somehow

They can be calculated as follows:

> *AL = ⌊TA / TQ⌋*, truncated to the cent
> *R = TA - AL × TQ*

For your example data, this works out as follows:

> *AL = ⌊8.13 / (2+3+11)⌋ = 0.50*
> *R = 8.13 - 0.50 × (2+3+11) = 0.13*

Then you would go through the list of items in descending order of quantity, so the largest quantity first:

> *E = ⌊R / Q<sub>i</sub>⌋*, rounded down to the cent
> *A<sub>i</sub> = AL + E*
> *R = R - E × Q<sub>i</sub>*

You could then optionally check if *R* has a smaller absolute value if you would add 1 more cent to the item with the smallest quantity.

This will not give the optimal solution, if optimal means that *R* must be closest to zero 0 whatever extreme differences one has to make between the different *A<sub>i</sub>*. But to get such results one would have to perform a further divisor analysis that would not always complete in linear time, and could lead to extremes where one item could cover for the whole add-on value, while all other items would get 0.00 add-on.

Back to the sample case: it will work out as follows:

> *E = ⌊0.13 / 11⌋* = 0.01
> *A<sub>3</sub> = 0.50 + 0.01 = 0.51*
> *R = 0.13 - 0.01 × 11 = 0.02*
>
> *E = ⌊0.02 / 3⌋* = 0.00
> *A<sub>2</sub> = 0.50 + 0.00 = 0.50*
> *R = 0.02 - 0.00 × 3 = 0.02*
>
> *E = ⌊0.02 / 2⌋* = 0.01
> *A<sub>1</sub> = 0.50 + 0.01 = 0.51*
> *R = 0.02 - 0.01 × 2 = 0.00*

```
+-----+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+
| Qty | Unit Price | Add-on | Price | Price with add-on |
+-----+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+
|   2 |      1.00  |  0.51  |  2.00 |    3.02           |
|   3 |      2.00  |  0.50  |  6.00 |    7.50           |
|  11 |      3.00  |  0.51  | 33.00 |   38.61           |
+-----+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+
|     |              Add-on:|  8.13 |                   |
|  15 |                     | 49.13 |   49.13           |
+-----+                     +-------+-------------------+
```

#### Second example

```
+-----+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+
| Qty | Unit Price | Add-on | Price | Price with add-on |
+-----+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+
|   5 |      1.00  |     ?  |  5.00 |       ?           |
|   5 |      2.00  |     ?  | 10.00 |       ?           |
|   5 |      3.00  |     ?  | 15.00 |       ?           |
+-----+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+
|     |              Add-on:|  0.17 |                   |
|  15 |                     | 30.17 |       ?           |
+-----+                     +-------+-------------------+
```

The algorithm would set:

> *AL = ⌊0.17 / (5+5+5)⌋ = 0.01*
> *R = 0.17 - 0.01 × (5+5+5) = 0.02*

... and the loop would not change anything since 2 cents is smaller than the smallest amount:

```
+-----+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+
| Qty | Unit Price | Add-on | Price | Price with add-on |
+-----+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+
|   5 |      1.00  |  0.01  |  5.00 |    5.05           |
|   5 |      2.00  |  0.01  | 10.00 |   10.05           |
|   5 |      3.00  |  0.01  | 15.00 |   15.05           |
+-----+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+
|     |              Add-on:|  0.17 |                   |
|  16 |                     | 30.17 |   30.15 (R = 0.02)|
+-----+                     +-------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to avoid rounding, not get a fair/even distribution

Comment: Could be. I have added a section about that.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I added more explanation to the original post. This procedure is need not for sales, more for purchasing - I do not believe there the "fairness" of the procedure will be an issue.

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let us measure all the prices in cents, so that only INTEGERS are involved.

The problem then becomes the following:

> Given several positive integers *a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>* (the quantities) and an integer *S* (the amount to add), find non-negative integers *p<sub>1</sub>, ..., p<sub>n</sub>* (the prices to add) so that *a<sub>1</sub>p<sub>1</sub> + ... + a<sub>n</sub>p<sub>n</sub> = S*.

As you already noticed, this problem does not always have a solution. There are two problems:

- For a solution to exist, the integer *S* must be divisible by the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) of *a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>*. Example:

> *a<sub>1</sub> = 4, a<sub>2</sub> = 6, S = 13*

This is a no-solution example, since both *a<sub>1</sub>* and *a<sub>2</sub>* are divisible by *2*, while *S* is not.

- If the above condition is satisfied, then there always exist solutions in INTEGERS (rather than NON-NEGATIVE INTEGERS). However, if *S* is too small, there still will be no solution in non-negative integers. Example:

> *a<sub>1</sub> = 4, a<sub>2</sub> = 7, S = 13*

This is still a no-solution example, although there are solutions in integers (e.g. 4 * 5 + 7 * (-1) = 13).

---

A complete algorithm will not be available without specifying how to deal with the no-solution case. But here I would like to give the link to [extended euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), which totally solves the case *n = 2*, and will certainly be a crucial tool to the final solution.